# Value entered in textbox of form1 not passed to label of form2

Tags: c#, winforms

I want the username entered in login form available in other forms.

Form1:

```
    private void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         .....

         FrmCreate_Invoice ci = new FrmCreate_Invoice(txtUsername.Text);

         .....
    }
```

Form2:

```
    public FrmCreate_Invoice(string usrnam)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string ausr = usrnam.ToString();
        label1.Text = ausr;
    }
```

}

Comment: On which line are you getting `NullReferenceException`

Comment: I guess `label1` is null? because if so you need to uncomment the `InitializeComponent()` line

Comment: on this line ' label1.Text = ausr;' @Nikolay

Comment: @tomer. yes u r right. the error is now solved. but i get label.text's value as 'label1' now.

Comment: i want the txtusrname entered in login form to b the label.text's value

Comment: How is that possible that `label1.Text` returns the name? What does `ausr` contain?

Comment: so you're simply doing `label1.Text = ausr` and right after this line `label1.Text` contains something else? or does it return something else after a few other lines of code?

Comment: @tomer , i resolved the issue. i had used FrmCreate_Invoice ci = new FrmCreate_Invoice(); again in the code below , so it had initiallized all the values. thats y i din get label.text. thank you. i now used property to get value from the parent form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `NullReferenceException` because `label1` is `null`.

As @Tomer suggested, uncomment `InitializeComponent();`.

Without `InitializeComponent` no components will be initialized therefore their values will be `null`.

Comment: Thank you. After i uncommented the initialize component line the error is not coming. but the label.text value still remains 'label1' :(